# Flask - strict_slashes redirects to http instead of https

Tags: python, nginx, flask, werkzeug

I have a flask server running on localhost:8080. I have set up nginx as a reverse proxy from my domain to localhost:8080 and have set up SSL. The automatic HTTPS works fine, except when Flask returns a 308 and redirects the client due to the strict_slashes rule. It redirects the user to a http URL instead of a https one, causing the page to not load. How do I make strict_slashes return redirects to a HTTPS url instead of a HTTP one.

Answer (score 0):

Since Flask url_for does not respect http or https while redirecting, always use `redirect(url_for('func_name', _external=True))` to respect the root URL and Scheme(http or https) used.

Alternatively, I used this in one of such cases to explicitly redirect to HTTPS

```
response_body = redirect(url_for('.route_function', _external=True))
response = app.make_response(response_body)
response.location = response.location.replace("http://", "https://")
return response
```